# Does setting the Authorization header for a POST cross-domain request always require a preflight?

Tags: javascript, cors

I was surprised recently to learn that when I set the `Authorization` header, my `POST` requests are getting preflighted. I had always assumed that the `Authorization` header would be exempted because of its ubiquity.

Is it true that the `Authorization` header is not special with respect to CORS, and therefore whenever you set the `Authorization` header, the browser must preflight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s true that whenever you add the `Authorization` header to a request, it triggers a preflight in browsers. That’s because `Authorization` isn’t defined as a [CORS safelisted request-header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header).

The list of CORS safelisted request-headers is quite short; it’s just `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Type`, `DPR`, `Downlink`, `Save-Data`, `Viewport-Width`, `Width`.

Any header added to a request that’s not in that list will trigger browsers to do a preflight.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the CORS safelisted request-headers.